# CSS selector which selects all of the same character in text?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there a way to select all of the same character in a block of text. For example if I wanted to make all of the a's in my text red. I could wrap them each in a span and do...

```
... Hello tod<span class="red">a</span>y is mond<span class="red">a</span>y ...
```

css

```
.red{
     color:red;
}
```

But this takes a long time and is hard to maintain.

I'm looking for something like this

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque auctor purus sed 
consequat maximus. Curabitur nunc nulla, volutpat accumsan aliquet eget, eleifend a 
leo. Pellentesque quis feugiat erat, vel cursus enim. Sed viverra mollis luctus. Proin 
ac lacus nulla. Fusce tincidunt, mauris vitae pulvinar pellentesque, lacus nisi sagittis
 mauris, vel luctus sapien dolor a ex. Donec dictum dui vitae pellentesque lacinia. Vivamus 
mattis venenatis varius.</p>
```

and for the css

```
p "a"{
    color: red;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: There's no such selector (although, how cool would it be!) However you could achieve this pretty easily with JavaScript.

Comment: Selectors select elements or pseudo-elements, but a character is neither. Maybe in the future you will be able to generate pseudo-elements to wrap the desired characters, but currently you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pure CSS I think is not possible to achieve that.

Many JavaScript supports the highlighting:

- http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-text-highlighter-plugins/
- http://james.padolsey.com/snippets/highlighting-text-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

If you decided to go Javascript, you could easily use a replace("a", "...") method.

```
var res = yourString.replace(/a/gi, "what ever you want");
```

Comment: That will only replace the first occurrence of `a`, use `replace(/a/g, "whatever")`

Comment: That will be case sensitive, use  str.replace(/a/gi, "whatever") for case insensitive

Comment: OP never asked for case insensitive but anyway :) And replace("a",...) is case-sensitive too